# Align button label in table cell

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-align

I have a hidden button with a visible label that I am trying to center align in a table cell.

```css
table {width: 150px}
table, td {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  text-align: center
}
label {
  background-color: red;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed
}
button {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>
    Some title
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <label><button></button></label>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

The label is not getting centered, and is overflowing the td. If I remove

> position: fixed

it is somewhat better, but the circle is getting squished. How can I improve this to get the desired result? Thanks :)

Also, what is happening here? I'd greatly appreciate references to learning material so that I can understand such CSS mysteries in a structured manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `position:fixed;` with `display:inline-block;`